# How can create a git merge but resolve to a known tree?

Tags: git, merge

After a git merge I had to resolve many conflicts, but then had to go back and make more changes. I did this with `git commit --amend` not realizing it would convert it into a regular commit.

What I want is for the merge commit to resolve to a known tree (where that work is already done). Is this possible?

E.g. start the merge, and when it tells me to resolve conflicts, I could do some kind of tree-only checkout that doesn't break the merge.

Comment: you're looking for `git rebase`.

Comment: In a sense, you should be aware of [commands that overwrite history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).  Your other branch still exists but if you try to merge it *now*, it'll conflict since the common ancestor isn't the same.

Comment: By the way, `git commit --amend` does not change a merge commit into a non-merge.  Something else must have gone wrong first.

Comment: @torek Well, I did several amends, a few via GitX's UI, so maybe that's to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary methods for doing this using plumbing commands, and one method that avoids plumbing commands entirely (so it is more verbose and takes longer but is more familiar).

Method one (fastest / most direct):

```
hash=$(git commit-tree -p $parent1 -p $parent2 -F $commit_msg_file $tree)
```

This new commit is a merge commit, using the given tree, and the given two parents.  You can now fast-forward a branch to this hash, or set a new branch pointing to it:

```
git branch newmerge $hash
```

Method two:

```
git checkout <branch>
git merge --no-commit <argument>
    (if merge conflicts occur, that's fine)
git read-tree --reset -u $tree
git commit
```

The only plumbing command magic here is `git read-tree`: `--reset` means kill off the current index, replacing it with the new tree, and `-u` means update the work-tree to match the change to the index.  Everything is now resolved and ready to commit.

Method three:

```
git checkout <branch>
git merge --no-commit <argument>
git rm -rf .             # run from top level: removes everything
git checkout $tree -- .  # likewise
git commit
```

This is the same as the `git read-tree --reset -u` method, except that it avoids plumbing commands, so that it's familiar.